# File Reading in C returns empty

Tags: c, file

I'm able to write data into a file but when I read it, it prints an empty file. I tried to make 2 programs one to write to file using permission "w" and one to read using "r" but when I combined both programs and changed permission to "w+" printing the files gives lots of empty spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{

    char name[20];
    char roll_no[15];
    char class[10];
    char semester[10];
    char course[20];

    FILE *file_pointer;
    file_pointer = fopen("StudentRecords.txt", "w+");
    if (file_pointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError Opening File StudentRecords.txt\nCreate File Manually and Try Again.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nENTER DETAILS FOR 5 STUDENTS\n");

    //TAKE 5 RECORDS FROM USERS AND SAVE THEM IN FILE-
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent %d", i);
        fprintf(file_pointer, "Student %d", i);

        printf("\nName : ");
        scanf("%s", &name);
        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nName : %s", name);

        printf("Roll No : ");
        scanf("%s", &roll_no);
        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nRoll No : %s", roll_no);

        printf("Class : ");
        scanf("%s", &class);
        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nClass : %s", class);

        printf("Semester : ");
        scanf("%s", &semester);
        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nSemester : %s", semester);

        printf("Course : ");
        scanf("%s", course);
        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nCourse : %s", course);

        printf("\n");
        fprintf(file_pointer, "\n\n");
    }

    //READ ENTIRE FILE WORD BY WORD
    char c;
    c = fgetc(file_pointer);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(file_pointer);
    }

    fclose(file_pointer);
}
```

Comment: i would open the file 'w', close it then reopen 'r'. Otherwise you have to rewind the file after you finish writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write/read in a file you use a stream (`FILE*`) that stores where in the file you are (position).

When you finished writting that was the *last stream position*.

You need to **go back to the begin of the file** if you want *to read it entirely*.

You can use `fseek` for this.

`int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);`

> 1  SEEK_SET : Beginning of file
>
> 2  SEEK_CUR : Current position of the file pointer
>
> 3  SEEK_END : End of file

```
...
//READ ENTIRE FILE WORD BY WORD
char c;

fseek(file_pointer, 0, SEEK_SET);

c = fgetc(file_pointer);
while (c != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(file_pointer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the read section do this instead. This will reset the position indicator to the beginning of the file so you can read from the beginning.

```
if ( fseek(file_pointer, 0L, SEEK_SET) == 0 ) { 
    char c;
    c = fgetc(file_pointer);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(file_pointer);
    }
}
```